# Build a catalogue of Tableau dashboards and data sources

Tags: tableau-api

I have a number of dashboards built and published online in Tableau. I'd like to build a catalog on all the dashboards with attributes such as **dashboard name, purpose, URL to access, person to contact** etc. so that the business stakeholders know which dashboard/report to go to for their needs.

Is there any advice on how to house this catalog within Tableau server? Should I end up building a Tableau report itself for this catalog? or any other better ways?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Tableau Server (not Cloud) then I would suggest setting up access to your `workgroup` database.

Follow this [guide](https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/perf_collect_server_repo.htm) for specifics, but the basics are :

1. Enable workgroup database access using TSM

`tsm data-access repository-access enable --repository-username readonly --repository-password <PASSWORD>`

2. Open Tableau Desktop and connect to the database using the postgresql connector.

Here is a custom query that could get you started once you are connected if you don't want to go through Desktop. You may need to add more fields depending on what you want to see. Keep in mind also that I wrote this years ago, so fields may have changed since. See the [Data Dictionary](https://tableau.github.io/tableau-data-dictionary/2023.3/data_dictionary.htm) for updates.

```
select s.name site, w.name workbook, wv.version_number, wv.published_at, w.updated_at, w.workbook_url, w.owner_name
    from workbooks w 
    left join sites s on w.site_id = s.id
    left join workbook_versions wv on w.id = wv.workbook_id
WHERE 1=1
    --upper(w.name) like '%MY DASHBOARD%'
group by 1,2,3,4,5
having w.updated_at = max(w.updated_at)
```

With this you can create an extract and publish that to Server to have live information.

Another option is `tableauserverclient` with Python, but I won't post all the details here because I suggest working within the above method. Good Luck!